# Word XML to HTML (with styling)

Tags: php, html, xml, ms-word

I have a word template (msword 2010) that I inject variables into using [PHPWord](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://phpword.codeplex.com/&ei=TuuHT7e5OMen0QXZ6Z27CQ&usg=AFQjCNGp-6D-s4fDHLosv1Biw3AFOUy99g), and would like to convert that into a PDF.

My thought process is to convert the word document into xml (which I have done), then turn that xml into styled html.

So far I have managed to replace the xml elements that represent line breaks and paragraphs, but am wondering if there is some code somewhere that will convert the other xml elements into styled html. I know it is unlikely to be perfect, but something close would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT). There are some good tutorials on the web. This [page](http://php.net/manual/en/xsl.examples.php) gives the code for doing this in PHP.

Comment: Helpful. Do you know of any generic xlst files that may help, as I have a dozen word files to do (and maybe more in the future)?

Comment: @Rooneyl - I do not know of any *generic* XSLT files. Once you pick it up it is quite easy to create the HTML you desire. You can ten use CSS to do the styling.